# Python write to text file only if ASCII value

Tags: python, utf-8

I am trying to write a program which will allow me to compare SQL files to each other and have started by writing the full SQL file to to a text file. The text file generates successfully, but with blocks at the end as in the below example:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON਍ഀ
GO਍ഀ
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON਍ഀ 
GO਍ഀ
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CDR](਍ഀ
```

Below this is the code that generates the text file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from _ast import Num 

#imports packages
r= open('master_lines.txt', 'w')

directory= "E:\\" #file directory, anonymous omission
master= directory + "master" 
databases= ["\\1", "\\2", "\\3", "\\4"]
file_types= ["\\StoredProcedure", "\\Table", "\\UserDefinedFunction", "\\View"]
servers= []
server_number= []
master_lines= []

for file in os.listdir("E:\\"):     #adds server paths to an array   
    servers.append(file)

for num in range(0, len(servers)):
    for file in os.listdir(directory + servers[num]):      #adds all the servers and paths to an array 
        server_number.append(servers[num] + "\\" + file)

master= directory + server_number[server_number.index("master")]

master_var= master + databases[0]

tmp= master_var + file_types[1]
for file in os.listdir(tmp):
    with open(file) as tmp_file:
        line= tmp_file.readlines()
    for num in range(0, len(line)):
        r.write(line[num])                      

r.close
```

I have already tried changing the encoding to both latin1 and utf-8; the current text file is the most successful as ascii and latin1 produced chinese and arabic characters respectively.

Below is the SQL file in text format:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CDR]    Script Date: 2017-01-12 02:30:49 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CDR](
    [calldate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [clid] [varchar](80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [src] [varchar](80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [dst] [varchar](80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [dcontext] [varchar](80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [channel] [varchar](80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [dstchannel] [varchar](80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [lastapp] [varchar](80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [lastdata] [varchar](80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [duration] [int] NOT NULL,
    [billsec] [int] NOT NULL,
    [disposition] [varchar](45) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [amaflags] [int] NOT NULL,
    [accountcode] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [userfield] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [uniqueid] [varchar](64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [cdr_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cost] [real] NOT NULL,
    [cdr_tag] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [importID] [bigint] IDENTITY(-9223372036854775807,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CDR_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [uniqueid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [ReadPartition]
) ON [ReadPartition]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [Idx_Dst_incl_uniqueId]    Script Date: 2017-01-12 02:30:50 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Idx_Dst_incl_uniqueId] ON [dbo].[CDR]
(
    [dst] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [uniqueid]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [ReadPartition]
GO
```

Hex dump to understand what happens, not part of above question:

```
ff fe 2f 00 2a 00 2a 00 2a 00 2a 00 2a 00 2a 00 
20 00 4f 00 62 00 6a 00 65 00 63 00 74 00 3a 00 
20 00 20 00 54 00 61 00 62 00 6c 00 65 00 20 00 
5b 00 64 00 62 00 6f 00 5d 00 2e 00 5b 00 43 00 
44 00 52 00 5d 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 53 00 
63 00 72 00 69 00 70 00 74 00 20 00 44 00 61 00 
74 00 65 00 3a 00 20 00 32 00 30 00 31 00 37 00 
2d 00 30 00 31 00 2d 00 31 00 32 00 20 00 30 00 
32 00 3a 00 33 00 30 00 3a 00 34 00 39 00 20 00 
50 00 4d 00 20 00 2a 00 2a 00 2a 00 2a 00 2a 00 
2a 00 2f 00 0d 00 0a 00 53 00 45 00 54 00 20 00 
41 00 4e 00 53 00 49 00 5f 00 4e 00 55 00 4c 00 
4c 00 53 00 20 00 4f 00 4e 00 0d 00 0a 00 47 00 
4f 00 0d 00 0a 00 53 00 45 00 54 00 20 00 51 00 
55 00 4f 00 54 00 45 00 44 00 5f 00 49 00 44 00
```

Result of hexdump:

```
../.*.*.*.*.*.*.
.O.b.j.e.c.t.:.
. .T.a.b.l.e. .
[.d.b.o.]...[.C.
D.R.]. . . . .S.
c.r.i.p.t. .D.a.
t.e.:. .2.0.1.7.
-.0.1.-.1.2. .0.
2.:.3.0.:.4.9. .
P.M. .*.*.*.*.*.
*./.....S.E.T. .
A.N.S.I._.N.U.L.
L.S. .O.N.....G.
O.....S.E.T. .Q.
U.O.T.E.D._.I.D.
```

Comment: You changed the encoding of database? or text file?

Comment: These "blocks" look like windows line breaks. Maybe it's just your editor showing non-printable characters. IMO encoding has nothing to do with it.

Comment: After magnifying the blocs, they contain 0D 0A for the former and 0D 00 for the latter. As OD is code for ascii Carriage Return and 0A is code for Line Feed (00 is code for Null used as  place holder), they look like a (badly written) end of line composed with Cr Cr Lf with reversed byte order. That can happen on Windows when you write text as 16 bits unicode (UTF16), and write end of lines as 8bits characters. You should show the code that produces the text file to confirm (or infirm)

Comment: @MYGz the encoding of how the text file is scripted from the Python file.

Comment: @mkiever Thanks but that still leaves me confused as to why default ascii encoding produces chinese characters?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I didn't write in an end of line. I attached my code as suggested if that helps

Comment: Please, explain what you mean by "changing the encoding to both latin1 and utf-8". It is very unclear what you are doing. You do not specify the encoding of the file you are writing, so you depend on the default on your computer.

Comment: @mkiever, the comment at the top of my code is supposed to change the encoding of any files written, as per [this website](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: @Sculler Wrong. Reread the PEP. You only tell Python how it should interpret the source code this way.

Comment: @mkiever but does the encoding of the source file not affect the encoding of any subsidiary files created, written to or in any way modified by the source code?

Comment: @mkiever also, as mentioned, if I leave that encoding line out it produces chinese characters in my text file

Comment: Could you show the content of one of the input files, preferently the one that contains the shown output?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have edited the post

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? And what editor are you using to see the *blocs*?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Python 3. And it seems editor irrespective; Notepad and Notepad++ produce the block. Notepad++ just does it with line breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the original files are encoded in UTF-16 with an initial Byte Order Mark. It is normally transparent on Windows because almost all file editors automatically read it thanks to the initial BOM.

But the conversion is not automatic for Python scripts! That means that every character is read as the character itself followed by a null. It is almost transparent except for end of lines, because the nulls are simply written back again to form normal UTF16 characters. But the `\n` is no longer preceded by a raw `\r` but with a null, as as you write in text mode, Python replaces it with a pair `\r\n` which is no longer a valid UTF16 character and this causes the bloc display.

This is trivial to fix, just declare the UTF16 encoding when reading files:

```
for file in os.listdir(tmp):
    with open(file, encoding='utf_16_le') as tmp_file:
```

Optionally, if you want to preserve the UTF16 encoding, you could also open the master file with it. By default, Python will encode it as utf8. But my advice would be to revert to 8bit encoding files to avoid further problem if you later wanted to process the output file.

Comment: Now it doesn't write a file at all

Comment: @Sculler: add traces in the code to see whether the lines are correctly read or not

Comment: I traced through and it's actually that code excerpt from above that stops the write  from occuring